# React renders only one GraphQL Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, plotly, plotly-dash, strapi

I am planning to build a chart based of 4 different GraphQL queries in order to make a simple bar chart. I am at beginning with dashboards so I learn how to make them.

As you can see in the pic bellow I get the data only from one query ==> the first one. How can I make my dashboard in order to retrieve to all queries and render the graph with all my Graphql queries?

Please see how the console log looks like  [console.log vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwf2V.png)

My full code is bellow:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

const total = gql`
query  total{
  webs{
    meta{
      pagination{
        total
      }
    }
      }
    }
`
const a = gql`
query GetIntell{
  webs(
    filters: { site :{eq: "a"}}
  ) {
    meta{
      pagination{
        total
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

const b = gql`
query GetIntell{
  webs(
    filters: { site :{eq: "b"}}
  ) {
    meta{
      pagination{
        total
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
const c = gql`
query GetIntell{
  webs(
    filters: { site :{eq: "c"}}
  ) {
    meta{
      pagination{
        total
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

export default function Test() {

  const { loading, error, data }= useQuery(c)
  const { loading2, error2, data2 } = useQuery(a);
  const { loading3, error3, data3 } = useQuery(b);
  const { loading4, error4, data4 } = useQuery(total);
  const [a, setA] = useState()
  const [b, setB] = useState()
  const [c, setC] = useState()
  const [d, setD] = useState()
  // const mitretotal = data3.webs.meta.pagination.total


  useEffect (() => {
      if (data)  {
        setA(data.webs.meta.pagination.total)
        
      }
    }, [data]
  )
  useEffect (() => {
    if (data2)  {
      setB(data2.webs.meta.pagination.total)
    }
  }, [data2]
)
  useEffect (() => {
    if (data3)   {

      setC(data3.webs.meta.pagination.total)
    }
  }, [data3]
)
  useEffect (() => {
    if (data4)   {

      setC(data4.webs.meta.pagination.total)
    }
  }, [data4]
)

  //const my = data.webs.data.id
  console.log("this is a", a);
  console.log("this is b", b);
  console.log("this is c", c);
  console.log("this is d", d);
  
  const chartData = [{
    y: [a, b, c ],
    x: ['cisa', 'nist', 'mitre'],
    type: 'bar'
  }]


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Plot
        data= {chartData}
        layout={ {width: 1000, height: 540, title: "Plot"} }
        //layout={ layout}
        config={{responsive: true}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of four `useState` and `useEffect` you can only do it one and show loader until you did not get the response from all the API and yeah do the error handling if API response failed timeout for that

```
const [barValue, setBarValue] = useState()

  useEffect (() => {
      if (data && data2 && data3 && data4)  {
        setBarValue({
a: data.webs.meta.pagination.total,
b: data2.webs.meta.pagination.total,
c: data3.webs.meta.pagination.total,
d: data4.webs.meta.pagination.total,
})
        
      }
    }, [data,data2,data3,data4]
  )

  //const my = data.webs.data.id
  console.log("this is a", barValue.a);
  console.log("this is b", barValue.b);
  console.log("this is c", barValue.c);
  console.log("this is d", barValue.d);
  
  const chartData = [{
    y: [a, b, c ],
    x: ['cisa', 'nist', 'mitre'],
    type: 'bar'
  }]


  return (
    <div className="container">
      {loading && loading2 && loading3 && loading4 ? LOADING...: null}
      {barValue? <Plot
        data= {chartData}
        layout={ {width: 1000, height: 540, title: "Plot"} }
        //layout={ layout}
        config={{responsive: true}}
      />: null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! Unfortunetly I got an error `this is barvalue undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue, by making a new column that stores all subtotals from my DB, and therefore I can do a one query that retrieves all my data in order to plot the plotly graph.